# Displaying hierarchical representation (indenting) without using the repeat() method

Tags: java

I need my output to be in hierarchical representation to look as such:

```
ClassA
     ClassC 
     ClassE
         ClassB
     ClassD
     ClassH 
ClassF
```

etc...

Now using the repeat() method, works properly however, it was not introduced till Java 11. Here is a snippet of what I currently have:

```
private final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
private int counter = 0;

@Override 
public void processVertex(E content){
    builder.append(" ".repeat(Math.max(0, counter)));
    builder.append(content).append("\n");
```

Is there a simple alternative to using the repeat() method so that this (indentation) would work properly in older versions of Java?

Comment: How much older we're talking?

Comment: Like around Java 8ish

Comment: `String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(counter, " "))`

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that takes the number of white spaces to print as an argument

```
static void printSpace(int spaceCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a function that returns a string with required amount of white spaces

```
static String printSpace(int spaceCount) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < spaceCount; i++) {
     sb.append(" ");
   }

   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much. I'm always hesitant to asking questions on here but this answered it perfectly!